# Alternative to HTMLUnit as headless browser in testing Spring Boot applications

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, htmlunit

So in our project we are using spring boot with thymeleaf and vanilla javascript to render web pages. Now while writing our UI tests we are currently using HTML Unit as a headless browser as it integrates rather well with spring boot.
However , whenever we use a little advanced calls like `array.flatMap` etc html unit fails as its engine does nit support those.
So we are looking for an alternative to explore to plugin into our environment.
Can someone please advise a headless browser that we can integrate . into our spring boot application ? Also if possible any documentation to integrate will help?
Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cypress running in a Docker container. To make this a bit easier you can use https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/testcontainers-cypress

Disclaimer: I am the author of the `testcontainers-cypress` library.

Comment: Quick question : I am looking to run the tests during a gradle build ? Will Cypress be   good candidate for that?

Comment: That should work. I am using it with Maven, but Gradle should work the same.

Comment: Great I will seek your help Once i start hooking it with my Spring app. Appreciate the response !

Comment: @bhattacharyya, how things worked with you ? What is your feedback ? I have the same need as you.

Comment: Cypress is a fair option to be honest. We as a team chose to go to https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/  to run the tests.